# Add target blank to JavaScript generated link

Tags: javascript, php, html

The script is used in a php file and it diplays a linked alexa rank image:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xslt.alexa.com/site_stats/js/t/a?url=x-invest.net"></script>
```

This is the result:

```
<a class="AlexaSiteStatsWidget" href="http://www.alexa.com/data/details/main?url=http://xxx">
<img alt="Alexa Certified Site Stats for xxx" src="http://xsltcache.alexa.com/site_stats/gif/t/a/eC1pbnZlc3QubmV0/s.gif" border="0">
</a>
```

I want to get target="_blank" in the < a > tag.
This is what i tried already:

```
<script>document.getElementsByClassName("AlexaSiteStatsWidget").setAttribute('target', '_blank');</script>

<script>$('#AlexaSiteStatsWidget a').attr('target', '_blank');</script>
```

But they both dont work.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`. You have to use a `for` loop to iterate through the elements. Also, why did you use `#` for a class in jQuery?

Comment: the keyword here is getElements. IOW it is getting more than one element so you either need to specify the index number ( document.getElementsByClassName("AlexaSiteStatsWidget")[0].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); ) or create a loop to process each element.

Comment: `#AlexaSiteStatsWidget` is looking for an element with the id of AlexaSiteStatsWidget which i do not see in your code. you need `.AlexaSiteStatsWidget` to select a class. also having `.AlexaSiteStatsWidget a` will look for child elements of whatever element has the class of AlexaSiteStatsWidget as such it wont find an `<a>` with the class of AlexaSiteStatsWidget unless there was another `<a>` inside it

Comment: thanks, jquery worked like this: `<script>$('.AlexaSiteStatsWidget').attr('target', '_blank');</script>`. I tryed all other solutons, they should work but they did not. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer. :)

Comment: There is no answer with this result^^

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:-

```
<script>document.getElementsByClassName("AlexaSiteStatsWidget").setAttribute("target","_blank");</script>
```

To this :-

```
<script>document.getElementsByClassName("AlexaSiteStatsWidget")[0].setAttribute("target","_blank");</script>
```

And remove this line :-

```
<script>$('#AlexaSiteStatsWidget a').attr('target', '_blank');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's gonna work but if you create an event listener on your <body>'s <a>s elements like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.querySelector("body a.AlexaSiteStatsWidget").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
 });
</script>
```

I didn't test it but i guess it gives you an idea of what i want to say

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of all nodes (html elements) with the class name provided. If you only have one html element with the specified class, it will still return an array containing one node.

If you want to apply this to one `<a>` element use:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("AlexaSiteStatsWidget")[0].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
</script>
```

If want to apply this to multiple `<a>` elements:

```
<script>
var alexaArray = document.getElementsByClassName("AlexaSiteStatsWidget");

for(var i = 0; i < alexaArray.length; i++){
   alexaArray[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
</script>
```